# DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged is not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

My main purpose, populating the ddlCity DropDownList according to the ddlMedicalName selection. But my main problem is, although I try almost every solution to that problem, I couldnt make it firing ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged .

I know, there is plenty of questions and answers about that problem, I have tried almos every one of them but still it doesn't work. I have read that EnableStateView=True should be applied not only to DropDownList but also to the whole page, So I have added the following code to the Web.Config:

```
 <system.web>
<pages styleSheetTheme="MainTheme" enableViewState="true"/>
```

And here is my code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;



namespace MedicalBootStrap
{

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Entity.medicaldbEntities context = new Entity.medicaldbEntities();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlBind();
        }

    }

    protected void ddlBind()
    {

        var orders = from order in context.Medicals

                     select new { order.MedicalID, order.medicalName, order.CityFK };

        var lstsrc = orders.ToList();

        ddlMedicalName.DataSource = lstsrc;
        ddlMedicalName.DataTextField = "medicalname";
        ddlMedicalName.DataValueField = "cityfk";

        ddlMedicalName.DataBind();

    }

    protected void ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

          int slc = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMedicalName.SelectedItem.Value);

        var orders = from order in context.Cities
                     where order.CityID == slc
                     select new { order.CityID, order.CityName};

        var lstsrc = orders.ToList();

        ddlMedicalName.DataSource = lstsrc;
        ddlMedicalName.DataTextField = "medicalname";
        ddlMedicalName.DataValueField = "cityfk";

        ddlMedicalName.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ddlRegion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }   
 }
}
```

And here is aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MedizinischeLeistungen.aspx.cs" Inherits="MedicalBootStrap.WebForm1" EnableViewState="true" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
<table id="SearchTable">
<tr>
<td>Medizinische Leistung</td>
<td>Region</td>
<td>Stadt</td>
</tr>
<tr id="SearchDropDown">

<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMedicalName" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" 
        AutoPostBack="True"  AppendDataBoundItems="true"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"> - Product - </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>

<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegion" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"
onselectedindexchanged="ddlRegion_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"> - Product - </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"
onselectedindexchanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"> - Product - </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Suche" onclick="SearchButton_Click" />

</td>
</tr>
</table>




</asp:Content>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: is the others dropdowns firing the event?

Comment: You didn't show the whole aspx page but do you have `AutoEventWireup="true"` set at the top?

Comment: @RômuloSpier I haven't tried it actually, I will give it a try.

Comment: @Icarus no I am adding it

Comment: @Icarus Ah sorry, since I have heard of it for the first time, I thought it was missing but it is already there and it is set to true

Comment: change OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged" to something random. If it is wiring properly, then you should get an exception on page render (since it can't find the event handler). If not, something is funky about the way ASPX is wiring your events

Comment: @SergueiFedorov I have changed it to something random and there is compilation error, does it mean, it is wiring correctly? by the way here is the error: "CS1061: 'ASP.medizinischeleistungen_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged2' and no extension method 'ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged2' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.medizinischeleistungen_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Yes. This means that, when the page renders, it can find the event handler in the backend code. This is good, because we know that the compiler is aware of the event and it's handler. The issue is somewhere else...

Comment: @mctuna run through with the debugger. The way postback works (I believe) in aspx is that it executes the entire page first, then fires your event. There is a chance that somewhere the request is ending and doesn't execute up to your event. 
EDIT: Ah, I see you already checked for postback. Check in medicaldbEntities to see what it does and if anything in there maybe signaling the end of the response...

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code. Here are what I found so far -

**ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged** event is fired correctly.

**ddlMedicalName.SelectedValue** is a string value; ***string is not a valid datasource*** for **ddlCity.DataSource**

```
protected void ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Problem is the following 3 line of codes.
    ddlCity.DataSource = ddlMedicalName.SelectedValue; 
    ddlCity.DataTextField = ddlMedicalName.SelectedValue;
    ddlCity.DataValueField = ddlMedicalName.SelectedValue;

    ddlCity.DataBind();
}
```

### Updated:

Here is how I test -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlBind();
    }
}

public class Medical
{
    public int MedicalID { get; set; }
    public string MedicalName { get; set; }
    public int CityFK { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}

protected void ddlBind()
{
    var medicals = new List<Medical>()
    {
        new Medical {MedicalID = 1, MedicalName = "One", CityFK = 11},
        new Medical {MedicalID = 2, MedicalName = "Two", CityFK = 22},
        new Medical {MedicalID = 3, MedicalName = "Three", CityFK = 33},
        new Medical {MedicalID = 4, MedicalName = "Four", CityFK = 44},
    };

    ddlMedicalName.DataSource = medicals;
    ddlMedicalName.DataTextField = "medicalname";
    ddlMedicalName.DataValueField = "cityfk";

    ddlMedicalName.DataBind();

}

protected void ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cities = new List<City>()
    {
        new City {CityID = 11, CityName = "City One"},
        new City {CityID = 22, CityName = "City Two"},
        new City {CityID = 33, CityName = "City Three"},
        new City {CityID = 44, CityName = "City Four"},
    };

    int slc = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMedicalName.SelectedItem.Value);

    var orders = from order in cities
                    where order.CityID == slc
                    select new { order.CityID, order.CityName };

    var lstsrc = orders.ToList();

    ddlCity.DataSource = lstsrc;
    ddlCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
    ddlCity.DataValueField = "CityID";

    ddlCity.DataBind();
}

protected void ddlRegion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: yes you are right, I have updated that part on the question, but still it is not firing

Comment: Sorry it is still string, which datatype should I choose? IQueryable? By the way I set breakpoint inside ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged but it is not hit, doesn't it mean, it is not being fired at all?

Comment: `ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged` event is fire everytime. ***Take out enableViewState="true" since it is not necessary.*** I don't know what you changed in your project, so make a new project and test the updated code. Also take a look at the code inside `ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: Yes (I don't know why but they rejected the change because edited part was too minor), I am trying your code, it is good to be sure that it is fired, thanks for your help, I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change as my suggestion and try.You have to remove the below line

```
ddlMedicalName.DataValueField = "cityfk";
```

**or**

Make a change cityfk to medicalname and try.

```
ddlMedicalName.DataValueField = "medicalname";
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
protected void ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```

to:

```
protected void ddlMedicalName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```

OR the opposite:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

to:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  EnableViewState="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddlCity_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
```

You are currently pointing to a handle named '..._SelectedIndexChanged' and are providing '..._OnSelectedIndexChanged'.

Comment: -1 - This does not matter, you can name method whatever you want, as long as the name matches what is in the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` attribute in the markup. You are misreading this, the OP has posted code that says `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged"`, which the OP has correctly done.

Comment: Why would that work if the actual method is called `ddlMedicalName_OnSelectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"
onselectedindexchanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged">

It is pointing to '..._SelectedIndexChanged' which DOES NOT EXIST!

Comment: You are right about ddlCity and ddlRegion but ddlMedicalName is correct.